# Send tarball to Amazon S3 - how to specify the region in the s3 url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I cannot figure out the url structure for an Amazon S3 bucket. My default region is US-West-2 so I know I need to specify it in the url, my current command is:

```
tar -cf /dev/stdout . | aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/myfile
```

I know that this isn't sufficient, how can I specify my organization/account and the region in my url? I want to be explicit.
Something like:

```
 aws s3 cp - s3://<my-account>.<aws-region>/<my-bucket>/myfile
```

does anyone know how to form the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When copying *to* an S3 bucket, use:

`aws s3 cp --region aws-region - s3://mybucket/myfile`

When copying *from* an S3 bucket, use:

`aws s3 cp --source-region aws-region s3://mybucket/myfile -`

This and more are available in `aws s3 cp help`